# In Applescript, finding only bold words in TextEdit causes app to hang

Tags: ms-word, applescript, textedit

just trying to find a vanilla applescript way of setting a variable to all bold words of a document. I've looked for ways using Applescript in Word, Pages & TextEdit and TextEdit seems to be the only one (could be wrong, though).

The good news is that the following script works but the bad news is if the document is over 2 pages with let's say ~50 bolded words, TextEdit hangs.

Any other ways to get bolded words using Applescript?

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    return words of text of document 1 where font contains "Bold"
end tell
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that TextEdit is being unreasonably slow. I just used the following code for a document with 3600 words, with some random bold words interspersed throughout. It took way too long. I'd look into using different scriptable app, like Tex-Edit Plus (still goin' strong, still great).
The reason I used both "Black" and "Bold" is that some fonts use a "Black" variant instead of "Bold" when you make the text Bold (at least in TextEdit). Just to be clear, the following code **works**, but it is painfully slow. It may be that your code, if you waited long enough, works, too. :-(  BUT keep reading :-)

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    tell document 1
        set thisManyRuns to count of attribute run of text of it
        repeat with r from 1 to thisManyRuns
            if font of attribute run r of text of it contains "Black" then
                --do stuff
                set color of attribute run r of text of it to {35555, 0, 0}
            end if
            if font of attribute run r of text of it contains "Bold" then
                --do stuff
                set color of attribute run r of text of it to {35555, 0, 0}
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

I just ran this text in Tex-Edit Plus and it completed in about two seconds:

```
tell application "Tex-Edit Plus"
    tell document 1
        set thisManyRuns to count of style run of text of it
        repeat with r from 1 to thisManyRuns
            set thisStyle to style of style run r of text of it
            if on styles of thisStyle contains bold then
                --do stuff
                set color of style run r of text of it to {0, 35555, 0}
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

... so you might want to switch to that. Just a caveat that I **had** to put the `style` into the `thisStyle` variable before querying for the `on styles` property -- it would not work if I tried to do that in one line. I was working with an rtf file.

Comment: (actually, less than that. it took 1.4 seconds with a document of 3600 words)